# Full-text search where word order doesn't matter

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have big MYSQL database and using version `MySQL 5.7.37` to search through my database with InnoDB engine.

Lets say I have record `"Reddish Brown is New Pink"`

If I search `Reddish Brown` then result appears only, otherwise no record found

So I want when I type `Brown Reddish` or `Pink Reddish Brown` so I get the same record

This is my search query

```
$q = trim(!empty($_POST['q'])) ? $_POST['q'] : null;
$key = $conn->real_escape_string(trim($q));

$conn->query("SET NAMES UTF8");
$sql = "SELECT id,title,time,category FROM data WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('$key') AND CONCAT(title, ' ') LIKE '%$key%' order by time desc LIMIT 20";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){ 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$id = $row['id'];
$title = $row['title'];
$time = $row['time'];
$category = $row['category'];
}}
```

Title field is set to `FULLTEXT` Index

Comment: What's the logic behind this? The record you've shared does not contain ` Brown Reddish`. Also, the query you've shared is widely open for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Are you searching for `+reddish +brown`? There's a lot of ways to use a full-text index, but I believe you're searching for "this exact text in this exact order" by default.

Comment: @tedman yes I want to search that record with different word order but right now its only working with exact order, how to make it work?

Comment: The `AND CONCAT(title, ' ') LIKE '%$key%'` requires the ordering.

Comment: @user3783243 how? this is my question, I have tried many ways but no luck, that's why I post a question.

Comment: @K.Mughal Why do you have/need that? The full text matching should do what that is trying to do.

Comment: @user3783243 I have users and they are searching with different word orders and if there is exact word order only then they get results otherwise no results, so I need the solution whether some one search with or without order will get the records

Comment: Delete `AND CONCAT(title, ' ') LIKE '%$key%'`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: @user3783243 If i remove what you say then there is no record found with the expected one, all other records are found with the matching first word

Comment: @K.Mughal Unclear what you mean. Wrong order would also fail with the `like`. a `like` for `brown red` with `red brown` won't match.

Comment: I have seen many websites with wrong order but giving the expected results so I want the same

Comment: Did you click the link? dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html See `IN BOOLEAN MODE`. You can put `+` for all required terms. Also relevant, https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-boolean-text-searches.aspx

Comment: I have tried countless options none worked for me

Comment: I can [make it work in a simple example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f9531/1).

Comment: How to make it work `AGAINST('+Reddish +Brown' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ` this option in my case ` AGAINST('$key' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` because this `$key` is a variable and its user's input

Comment: You're using PHP, so you can add the plusses with a bit of code: `$key = '+' . implode(' +', explode(' ', $key));` or `$key = '+' . str_replace(' ', ' +', $key);`. These examples are not perfect by any means, but I think the idea is clear?

Comment: Thanks a lot @KIKOSoftware your suggestion worked pretty well as I wanted, please vote up my question if you think what I asked was a worth.

Comment: OK. Just keep in mind that the code is not perfect. What will happen if there are 2 spaces in succession? You need to find a better algorithm to extract the words.

Comment: I will do the rest thanks once again